# Return type checking in Flow

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

Is Flow supposed to check return types? It doesn't seem to for custom types - the following code compiles just fine:

```
function test1(value: number) : Distance {
  if (value == 4) {
    return "asd";
  }
  if (value == 5) {
    return { a: 9 };
  }
  if (value == 6) {
    return null;
  }

  return new Distance(value);
};
```

Distance is defined like this:

```
export class Distance {
  value: string;
  unit: string;

  constructor(value: string, unit?: SDKConstants.MeasurementUnit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.unit = unit;
  }
}
```

This compiles on Flow just fine. I noticed that if I change the return type to number, then I get some errors.

Can some explain the limitations of Flow in this case? Do I need a setting in a config to make it more strict or what?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Distance was defined in a separate file which didn't have `@flow` tag. The alternative is to enable Flow checking in all files (https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-all-boolean)